# How can get last index in Scapy packet?

Tags: python, scapy

I am using Scapy to craft and sniff packets. I am trying to get last payload index of the sniffing packet. For example:

```
p=IPv6()/UDP()/DHCPv6_Solicit()
```

DHPCv6_Solicit() will be the last payload and the index for it is 2

```
p[2] #print DHCPv6_Solicit() object
```

I tried to get the last index by using -1 but the Scapy gave me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
   exec(code, self.locals)
   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 966, in __getitem__
   raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % lname)
IndexError: Layer [-1] not found
```

I tried to get length of the array by using

```
len(p2)
```

but Scapy showed the length of the packet in bytes
So how can I find the last payload index of the Scapy packet?

Comment: What is `p2`? What exactly is the error when using `p[-1]`?

Comment: I update the question

Comment: Which Scapy version are you use?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `packet.lastlayer()`:

```
>>> p = IPv6()/UDP()/DHCP6_Solicit()
>>> p.lastlayer()
<DHCP6_Solicit  |>
```

You could also use `packet.layers()` and use list indexing the way you were expecting:

```
>>> p.layers()
[<class 'scapy.layers.inet6.IPv6'>, <class 'scapy.layers.inet.UDP'>, <class 'scapy.layers.dhcp6.DHCP6_Solicit'>]
>>> p.layers()[-1]
<class 'scapy.layers.dhcp6.DHCP6_Solicit'>
```